# Conditional probability and extraction without replacement

Tags: probability

Inside a box, there are $10$ balls numbered from $1$ to $10$, which are extracted without replacement. $X_n$ is a random variable that represents the result of the $n^{\text{th}}$ extraction.
Evaluate $$P(X_5>\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)|X_5=7).$$

By definition, $$\Pr(X_5>\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)|X_5=7)=\frac{\Pr(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)<7,X_5=7)}{\Pr(X_5=7)}.$$

But now I'm stuck: I don't know how to evaluate $\Pr(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)<7,X_5=7)$.

Answer (score 1):

$ Pr(\max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) < 7, X_5 = 7) $ is the probability that all of the first four extractions result in numbers less than $7$, and that the fifth extraction is exactly $7$.

Since the balls are extracted without replacement, the total number of possible outcomes for the first four extractions is the number of ways to choose $4$ different balls from $10$, which is $ \binom{10}{4} $.

Now, let's calculate $ Pr(\max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) < 7, X_5 = 7)$. To satisfy the condition $ \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) < 7 $, the first four balls must be chosen from the balls numbered $1$ to $6$. There are $ \binom{6}{4} $ ways to do this because we're choosing $4$ balls out of the $6$ that are less than $7$.

After removing these $4$ balls, there are $6$ balls left, one of which is the ball numbered $7$, so the probability of the 5th extraction being a ball numbered $7$ is $
frac{1}{6}$

This gives us:

$$ Pr(\max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) < 7, X_5 = 7) = \frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{84}$$

Next, we calculate $ Pr(X_5=7) $. The probability that the fifth ball is the ball numbered 7 given that the first 4 balls drawn are not numbered 7 is $ \frac{1}{6} $(because there are 6 balls left after drawing 4 balls).

The probability that the first 4 balls drawn are not numbered 7 is $\frac{\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$, where the numerator represents the number of ways to draw 4 balls from the 9 that are not numbered 7 and the denominator represents the total possible outcomes of drawing $4$ balls from a set of $10$.

So we have:

$$ Pr(X_5=7) = \frac{\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{10}$$

Now we can calculate the conditional probability:

$$ Pr(X_5 > \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) | X_5 = 7) = \frac{Pr(\max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) < 7, X_5 = 7)}{Pr(X_5=7)} $$

$$ Pr(X_5 > \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) | X_5 = 7) = \frac{\frac{1}{84}}{\frac{1}{10}} $$

$$ Pr(X_5 > \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) | X_5 = 7) = \frac{10}{84}$$
$$ Pr(X_5 > \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) | X_5 = 7) = \frac{5}{42}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the numerator $N$, the first four umordered selections must be from balls $1-6$ followed by ball $7$, thus $Pr = \Large\frac{\binom64}{\binom{10}4}\cdot\frac16$

For the denominator $D$, the first four unordered selections must be from $9$ balls (excluding ball $7$) followed by ball $7$, thus $Pr=\Large\frac{\binom94}{\binom{10}4}\cdot\frac16$

and the desired probability, cancelling out common terms is

$Pr = \Large\frac{N}{D} = \frac{\binom64}{\binom94}$